# How to maintain order of tasks for asynchrounous operations using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a java application where the central datastructure will be updated both with the request and corresponding response from external systems.
How can I make sure there are no race conditions? Below is how I implemented.

I receive request from GUI and I process it and store in hashmap of hashmap and then forward the request to external system for which I get the response asynchronously. When I receive the response based on some id that I sent earlier, I update the datastructure (hashmap of hashmap)

I created one thread that handles request from GUI and another for handling responses from external system.
I have created 2 linkedblockingqueues - one for requests and another for responses

I am using executor service to create multiple threads for request & response.
How do I make sure things are executed in order ? 
This is an order management system and I dont want an amend to be sent before new order is sent.

Comment: If you’re using queues, your requests are already in order, aren’t they?

Comment: yes but do we need to use the same queue for both request and response. If so is the performace going to be affected?

Comment: Are you asking how to process multiple requests simultaneously, even if they finish out of order, while still keeping them in a queue that preserves the request order?  You probably need a PriorityQueue for that, based on an ordered request number or other sortable request attribute (like a date).

Answer (score 1):

Use Hastable, it is the synchronized implementation of a Map.

The synchronized implementation will prevent that more than one thread accesses it at the same time.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html